# Issue with CASE operator - using different data type "Distinct types: I8,StringBuffer"

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, adx

I'm having an issue with trying a pretty straightforward case in KQL, while I'm trying to set a dependency of the 'Breakdown by' field (a field that enables to breakdown of the graphs in various ways) with a CASE/ Meaning in case that my 'Breakdown by' field is set to 'campaign_final' I would like to remove all 'Organic' traffic from the data
Seems like the go-to way is CASE - but I'm always open to any other operational way :)

The relevant script is:

```
let breakdown = 'campaign_final';  
    MyTable 
    | where install_date >= ago(30d)  
    | extend dim = column_ifexists(breakdown,"ERROR") 
    | extend dim = case(dim == campaign_final, isnotempty(campaign_final), tostring('error')) 
    | sample 30
```

I'm getting the below error:
case: return types are not compatible. Number of different types: Distinct types: I8,StringBuffer.

What am I missing here? why isn't the last 'error2' isn't a string?

I would like that when `dim == campaign_final` then all the empty (Organic traffic) campaign_final will be removed from the data

Many thanks!

I tried to switch data types, using null values, and changing different parameters in the script

Answer (score 0):

look at the argument for the following statement:

```
case(
    dim == campaign_final,
    isnotempty(campaign_final),
    'error'
)
```

the first argument is of type `bool`, it's the condition you're evaluating.

the second argument (chosen if the condition is `true`) is of type `bool`, which is the return type of the function `isnotempty()` that you're using.

the third argument (chosen if the condition is `false`) is of type `string`.

i.e. - you have a type mismatch between the types of the 2nd and 3rd arguments, as the `case` statement can return only a specific type, and that type can't be conditional.

> I would like that when dim == campaign_final then all the empty (Organic traffic) campaign_final will be removed from the data

i didn't understand this part. you may want to clarify your desire using a simple example - a small input data set, and the desired output that matches it.